# why is IE8 loading javascripts incompletely?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm running IE8 in normal mode (whatever it is when compatibility is NOT turned on) on WinXP. I'm doing maintenance on a rails app that was written a few years ago. Often when I load a page, and/or refresh a page, it reports different javascript errors. When I look at the errors in the Developer tool, it appears that a javascript file hasn't loaded completely. So the errors are frequently syntax related, such as `'}' expected`.

Comment: have you verified the source file does not match up with the loaded file ?  Just because other browsers don't error, doesn't mean there isn't an error in the javascript.  Some browsers are just more tolerant.  The chances that ie is erroring because of a partial load is pretty unlikely.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll give that a try; however, part of the problem is that this app is using a bunch of library scripts like parts of jquery and others from a few years ago; they seem to have not aged particularly well; there are about 20+ js includes in the main app wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Trailing comma in object literal or array declaration? Some browsers accept this without error, IE does not.

```
// Trailing commas are bad
var someArray = [
    "thing",
    "last",
];
var someObject = {
    one: "thing",
    after: "another",
};
```

As galambalazs suggested in his comment, [jslint](http://jslint.com/) will pick up problems like this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cntrl + F your javascript file and look for a rogue "return" statement.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on older versions of IE.  It was never reproducible in a test harness and left no trace in server logs, but consistently affected a very small percentage of IE 6 loads.

The solution was to have the embedding HTML file double check that the JS was loaded.

foo.js:

```
// do all the real work.

// As the last statement, set a variable indicating completion.
foo_js_fully_loaded = true;
```

foo.html:

```
<script src=foo.js></script>
<script>if (!foo_js_fully_loaded) { /* reload the page */ }</script>
```